# How to pull other serialized data from different Serializer classes?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to pull the permissions data into my UserSerializer. I have a Many To Many relationship with User to Group with a through table called GroupUser. I'm able to pull the group_id and the group_name, but I can't seem to populate the data for permissions into my User Serializer.
So far I've tried using `permission = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.permissions')` but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = GroupUserSerializer(source='groupuser_set', many=True)
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(source='permission_set', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'users', 'permissions', 'role', )

class GroupUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.id')
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.name')
    class Meta:
        model = GroupUser
        fields = ( 'id', 'name', )

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     tests = TestSerializer(source='test_set', many=True)
     groups = GroupUserSerializer(source='groupuser_set', many=True)
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'groups', 'tests', )
```

I want my data to look like this:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "user",
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "employee"
            "permission": "Access-Denied"
        }
    ],
    "tests": []
},
```

but I have it without "permissions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     tests = TestSerializer(source='test_set', many=True)
     groups = GroupSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'groups', 'tests', )
```

Edited explanation:
I was able to find the answer with a little tinkering.
I thought, from reading docs and stackoverflow questions, you had to include the 'Through' table when referencing a many to many relationship, but that's not true, the serializer already does it for you.
So I added the groups, as shown, with that information and all the data that is associated in the GroupSerializer with a relationship with data was populated just like the way I want it to be.

Comment: Some details about why this is an answer, and how it works, would be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'll keep that in mind when I answer my own questions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write a new Serializer for your UserSerializer, this will not affect other Serializers:

```
class GroupForUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = GroupUserSerializer(source='groupuser_set', many=True)
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(read_only=True , many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'permissions' )
```

Then you can in your `UserSerializer` use `GroupForUserSerializer` now:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     tests = TestSerializer(source='test_set', many=True)
     groups = GroupForUserSerializer(source='groupuser_set', many=True)
     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'id', 'username', 'groups', 'tests' )
```

Comment: I've tried this method before, but it didn't work for me.